# How much for a European trip?

Tags: budget, europe, food-and-drink, hotels, western-europe

I want to go on a European trip with four of my friends during October for one week.

How much will be the estimated cost (staying in a decent hotel + food) for the trip per head?

Any critical cost-cutting tip(s) appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any specific locations in mind that you wish to cover? As it stands, this question is too broad.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. Costs will depend on the countries involved, special events happening during these times, what you consider a "decent" hotel, how many people in a room, whether you stay in the city center or farther away, whether food is anything from the cheapest fast food to world-renowned restaurants, and what you do for sightseeing and attractions. The good news is that lots of cost information is available online, and you can take advantage of that. Start searching hotel booking sites for cities you're interested in and look at the options.

Comment: Visit Germany and Spain particularly. Visit all tourist attraction spots.

Comment: It's quite easy to price out such a trip using online resources.  Is there some specific aspect you're looking at?

Comment: Are you planning to visit both Spain and Germany during the week? If so, the mode of travel from one to the other will have a significant impact on the cost. If not, the choice of Germany or Spain will likely have an impact on the cost.

Comment: Europe varies enormously in terms of costs. Pick a cheap country if budget is limited. Spain and Greece are much cheaper than Germany and Switzerland for example.

Comment: Germany and spain are big countries which are impossible to cover in a week. You will have to narrow down your plan (and question) to something which is manageable in a week. Say you can pick Berlin in germany and Madrid/Barcelona or both in Spain. Costs will then be cost of hotels and local travel and air/rail travel between your chosen cities plus sundry expenses.

Answer (score 4):

Visiting *all* the tourist attractions will be impossible. If you try it, you will see nothing in any detail. Make a plan. History, culture, nature?

In Germany, beds can go from €15 per night in a backpacker hostel to €100 or more per night in a hotel. Cheap hostels may not be available in smaller cities, and some larger cities can be *much* more expensive during peak seasons (Munich during the Oktoberfest.)

- Consider if you can (and want to) stay in a [youth hostel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Youth_Hostel_Association). Check about membership in your national youth hostel association and if that allows you into hostels [abroad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostelling_International). You might be able to get one room together with your friends.

A meal fast-food place is €5 to €10 per person, depending on how hungry you are. A cheap restaurant would be €10 to €20.

- A way to cut cost is to go to a supermarket, buy a bottle of soda, a loaf of sliced bread, plus cheese, sausage, etc. and to make yourself sandwiches. €5 to €20 will be enough for a meal for five. You can find a place to eat e.g. in a park, that's generally acceptable if you clean up afterwards. Either buy disposable plastic cups, cardboard plates, and plastic knives, or bring a more substantial plastic cup that can be cleaned in the bathroom sink at the evening. If you want hot drinks to go with the meal, buy takeaway coffee in a bakery, not in a restaurant.

For travel, it depends on how often and how far you want to ride. Consider a [rail pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurail), individual train tickets, or intercity bus tickets.